# $E[X_i^2]$ if I already know $E[X_i]$.

Tags: probability, means

I have calculated $E[X_i] = \frac{2}{3}$ and therefore I know that $E[X_1] = \frac{2}{3}$. Now I want to calculate $E[X_1^2]$. Is it correct to calculate with the following process?

$E[X_1^2] = E[X_1 \cdot X_1] = E[X_1] \cdot E[X_1] = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}$

X1 can either be 1 or 0.

No variance is included in the problem I have to solve.

Edit: The above formula is incorrect. The correct one is the one at the accepted answer.

Comment: No, this is not correct.  Suppose $X$ takes values $\pm 1 $ each with probability $\frac 12$.

Comment: When two random variables are statistically independent, the expectation of their product is the product of their expectations. You can't use this when the random variables are not independent.

Comment: Xi can either be 1 or 0.

Comment: Worth remarking:  since $Var (X) = E[X^2]-\left( E[X] \right)^2$, we only have $E[X^2]= \left( E[X] \right)^2$ when the Variance is $0$.

Comment: The property of  [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) does  exist. But a similar property for the $\texttt{product}$ is not true in general.

Comment: Note:  if you are assuming that $X$ can only take the values $0,1$ then you should add that to your question.

Comment: @lulu Did that, edited the question.

Comment: If $P(X_i\in\{0,1\})=1$ then $X_i^2=X_i$ almost surely hence $E(X_i^2)=E(X_i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_i$ is either $1$ or $0$ it follows that
$$
2/3=E(X_1)=P(X_1=1).
$$
Hence
$$
E(X_1^2)=1^2P(X_1=1)+0^2P(X_1=0)=2/3.
$$